# File is located from another project, but won't read or load into arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to use a file from one project in a new project. The code has no errors in debugging, but skips to my programmed error "Problem reading data from file." Any attempt to run the program anyway results in a calculation of 0 - because the arrays don't seem to be populating.

Thanks for the help.

```
'opens the text file, reads it, stores the value in two arrays
    'closes the file

    Dim srFileName As String   'Name the file to be opened
    Dim intNumItems As Integer  'number of records on file
    Dim i As Integer            'loop counter for the array 
    Dim intLastBlank As Integer
    Dim strInput As String

    srFileName = "C:\StudentMarks.txt"



    If File.Exists(srFileName) Then
        Dim srReader As New StreamReader(srFileName)

        Try

            intNumItems = srReader.ReadLine()
            strInput = srReader.ReadLine()

            Do While srReader.Peek >= 0

            Loop
            strInput = srReader.ReadLine()


            While Not srReader.EndOfStream

                'each loop iteration, reads 2 lines and places in proper array
                For i = 0 To intNumItems - 1

                    'find location of tab between student name and mark
                    intLastBlank = strInput.IndexOf(vbTab)
                    'take characters before tab and place in name array
                    arrName(i) = strInput.Substring(intLastBlank + 1)
                    'take characters after tab, convert to double, and
                    'place values in mark array
                    arrMark(i) = Double.Parse(strInput.Substring(intLastBlank + 1))

                Next
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Problem reading data from file")
        End Try
```

Comment: Your code has errors when debugging, but they're being caught by your `Try/Catch` block and not dealt with as you don't even show the actual error message. :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You really should make your MessageBox display the actual error message too. It will help you troubleshooting the problem.

Example:

```
MessageBox.Show("Problem reading data from file:" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message)
```

---

Anyhow, as for your problem you have created an infinite loop here:

```
Do While srReader.Peek >= 0
    'You have no code here, so you've created yourself an infinite loop.
Loop
strInput = srReader.ReadLine()
```

You probably misplaced the `Loop` keyword. I'm guessing it's supposed to be further down the code?

---

**EDIT:**

I also don't understand the point of using both:

```
Do While srReader.Peek >= 0
```

...and:

```
While Not srReader.EndOfStream
```

You only need to use one of the statements, as both of them checks wether there is more for the `StreamReader` to read.

Also make sure you put the `.ReadLine()` methods within the loop. :)

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't learned how to add an error message to the catch. It came up with "can't convert type string to int" So I'm assuming that means my array is defined as String and my code is loading an int. What I'm confused about is how I would load a string type without converting to int though. I'll try to do more research in the meantime.

Comment: @Cayris: this statement `intNumItems = srReader.ReadLine()` is trying to assign a String (returned by `ReadLine`) to an Integer (`intNumItems`). If the line can't be converted into an Integer, you will get that error. Run the code in the debugger and see what the value is. You should also turn `Option Strict On` to flag as compile time errors all statements that might have this problem.